# Где лучше хранить данные о пользователях во время работы приложения

Tags: база-данных, хранение-данных, класс

Пишу тг бота на Python. Бот не большой, порядка 100 пользователей.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где лучше хранить данные о пользователях (фио, принадлежность к рабочим группам, номер телефона, и т.п.) во время работы приложения: в памяти программы (класс User) или в базе данных (в данном конкретном случае sqlite3)?

Comment: Хранение в памяти бота подразумевает, что одновременно может быть запущен только один экземпляр бота, что затруднит горизонтальное масштабирование в будущем

Comment: так и есть. большего и не требуется. Бот информационный, для внутренней кухни.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего хранить в базе данных. Иначе не сможете перезапустить бота, все данные пропадут.

Comment: вопрос не про хранение данных для последующего перезапуска, а про хранение данных во время работы приложения. Понятное дело что для восстановления данных при перезапуске их нужно в бд сохранить. Но меня интересует эффективное хранение с постоянным чтением непосредственно по время работы бота.

Comment: Если по эффективности, эффективнее будет хранить в памяти программы, оттуда быстрее можно достать. Но какой выбрать, зависит от конкретней задачи.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

По хорошему и там, и там. Если делать запись и чтение на любое действие, то это может негативно сказаться на работе внешнего накопителя. Однако если хранить всё в оперативной памяти, то любое непредвиденное выключение машины ведёт к потере всех данных. В вашем случае пользователей не много, хранить все данные можно в оперативке, однако периодически стоит делать записи, желательно раз в 10 минут, не медленнее (зависит от того, насколько у вас стабильный сервер). Читать 100% стоит только из оперативки, так как опять же, я сомневаюсь что вам её не хватит.

Но всё тут всё зависит от ситуации. Если данных у вас редко меняются, то можно записывать их каждый раз при изменении.

Если же говорить про скорость чтения, то почти всегда выигрывает оперативная память, а учитывая, что ваша база данных достаточно малая, подойдёт и обычный словарь встроенный в язык

Comment: Изменения в данных о пользователе происходят единожды - в момент регистрации пользователя. Далее только чтение.
Получается я верно предполагал. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Enreward_Ronkhall В таком случае храните всё в оперативке, но при регистрации сохраняйте в любую базу данных (можно хоть в файл в виде json), разницы особо не будет) Таким образом данные будут и в безопасности, и в быстром доступе, а при перезагрузке можно будет легко подгрузить все данные из файла за 1 раз. удачи!